# indent-region does not respect my c-mode style

Tags: indentation, lsp-mode, align, lsp

This is my C style:

```
(defconst mira-c-style
  '((c-basic-offset . 4)
    (indent-tabs-mode . nil)
    (tab-width . 7)
    (c-comment-only-line-offset . (0 . 0))
    (c-lineup-C-comments . 0)
    (c-electric-pound-behavior. alignleft) ; Pre-processor macros go to column 0
    (paragraph-start . "[   ]*\\(//+\\|\\**\\)[     ]*$\\|@param\\)\\|^")
    (c-offsets-alist . ((topmost-intro-cont    . 0)
                        (statement-block-intro . +)
                        (knr-argdecl-intro     . 5)
                        (substatement-open     . 0)
                        (substatement-label    . +)
                        (label                 . +)
                        (statement-case-open   . +)
                        (statement-cont        . +)
                        (arglist-intro  . +)
                        (arglist-close  . 0)
                        (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
                        (access-label   . 0)
                        (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
                        (cpp-macro . [0])
                        )))
  "Mira C Programming Style")
(c-add-style "Mira C" mira-c-style)
(setq c-default-style "Mira C")
```

I then use this fake function for testing:

```
int func(void) {
    sub_function(quite_a_long_arg, very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_arg);
}
```

If I add a newline between the two arguments, I get what I expect:

```
int func(void) {
    sub_function(quite_a_long_arg,
        very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_arg);
}
```

If I run `indent-region` on the whole function, I get this:

```
int func(void) {
  sub_function(quite_a_long_arg,
               very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_arg);
}
```

I do not want this alignment. It does not respect the style definition above (I think?).

I suspect that clangd might be involved in this, I am using it through lsp mode. In real-life code it also breaks strings into sub-strings for the sake of column requirements, which is a big no-no for me.

What is causing this? How do I get control about it? How do I force `indent-region` to respect my C style?

Emacs 28.1 with lsp, clangd.

Comment: If you are using lsp, you should first douible–check that `lsp-mode` isn’t sending your code off to `clangd` to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the `:init` section of my init file, so far so good:

```
(setq lsp-enable-indentation nil)
(setq lsp-enable-on-type-formatting nil)
```

I'm not sure yet if there are other formatting options to turn off.

My current (working?) snippet from init.el:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  ;; set prefix for lsp-command-keymap (few alternatives - "C-l", "C-c l")
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  (setq lsp-enable-indentation nil)
  (setq lsp-enable-on-type-formatting nil)
  :hook (
         (c-mode . lsp-deferred)
         (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :ensure t)
```

Comment: If you have a good file respecting Mira style, then open it (without lsp) and from menu Cc-mode select ```Guess style from file``` and then ```View style``` - you can further save the style and name it Mira.

Comment: @Ian This would be to create a C style, but without the lsp setup above, lsp would still try to correct it, right?

Comment: Yes, but ```lsp``` is only the
interface for ```clang-format``` - the parameters can be trimmed with the
variable
[lsp-clients-clangd-args](https://gist.github.com/nelimee/120e536add6905db4d107ddffd29c097).
No - so why not really use clang-format to work for you - the
[clang-format docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) show how to get
a formatting style and use it as template for your case - here the
[clang-format style](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)
is detailed, including ```veryveryverylong``` indentation case.

Comment: @Ian I tried to make clang format like my company wants it, a few years ago. I was missing some options, and `uncrustify` allowed me to do what was needed. Now we run uncrustify before commit anyway, but I want to format approximately correctly while writing, it's easier to read. It's awkward to have clangd auto-format with its default config, which looks vastly different, when what I wrote already looks like the correct format.